# How to run Java my project with eclipse

Tags: java

I have started learning Java and I have 1 issue:

I write a simple class and it runs and everything's fine.
I took all the project from my Laptop to my other computer and from Eclipse I choose "File --> Open File" and choose my .java file.

When I try to run my program this windows pop up:

[image]

and after trying both option nothing happen.

How can I run my program and what is the problem ?

Comment: Try making a project, then go to Run > Run Configurations. Then just create a new Java Application Run Config, select your project and main class file, the hit Run.

Comment: you mean try making a new one ?

Comment: Yeah, on your other computer, go to New > Java Project and make a new one. Then import your java files and do the process I described above to run your new project. It _should_ work after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform the following steps:

1. Create a new project in ***eclipse***
2. Link your classes from the project properties' ***buildpath***
3. Go to Run->Run Configurations
4. Create a new ***configration***
5. Point your ***main*** class
6. And Run

Comment: thanks ! BTW that what is the best site for JAVA (like microsoft MSDN)?

Answer (score 0):

if you are just starting learning Java and dont understand whats going on with all that stuff with eclipse, I would recommend you to start from the basics, write your code in an ordinary text editor (notepad will do, or notepad++ if you want something more), after you have written and saved your source file, open up your command prompt, navigate to the location of the file, and run:

```
javac YourFileName.java
java YourFileName
```

here is more detailed guide:http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/15inout/windows-cmd.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with learning Java with Eclipse or any other IDE.  If you move file from one computer to the other you need as it was said start a new project or you can use existing project and import files.  In order to import files right click on a project and click then Import and select files.  Then you should be able to run your class.  Also be sure to have the Java perspective selected when you work on your class.

Comment: Whats this Java perspective ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to create your public class and then just click on the green button with the white triangle on it ;)
See here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TEtI.png